# Scraping Wikipedia Table providing no results

Tags: python

venturing into the world of python. I've done the codeacademy course and traweled through stack and youtube but hitting an issue I cant solve.

I'm attempting to do a simple print of a table located in wikipedia, failing misreably at writing my own code I decided to use a tutorial example and build off. However this isn't working and I haven't the foggest idea why.

This is the code here with the appropiate link included. My end result is an empty list "[ ]". I'm using PyCharm 2017.2, beautifulsoup 4.6.0, requests 2.18.4 & python 3.6.2. Any advice appreciated. For reference, the tutorial website is [here](https://roche.io/2016/05/scrape-wikipedia-with-python)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

WIKI_URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_volcanoes_by_elevation"

req = requests.get(WIKI_URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'lxml')
table_classes = {"class": ["sortable", "plainrowheaders"]}
wikitables = soup.findAll("table", table_classes)

print(wikitables)
```

Comment: change `table_classes = {"class": ["sortable", "plainrowheaders"]}` to `table_classes = {"class": "sortable"}`?

Comment: No luck, same result.

Comment: Sorry i meant without creating it as a list. See my edited json above.

Comment: Still no luck, removed square brackets and printing as list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish that using regular expressions.

1. You get site content by `requests.get(WIKI_URL).content`
2. See source code of the site to see how Wikipedia presents tables in HTML.
3. Find a regular expression that can fit whole table (might be something like `<table>(?P<table>*+?)</table>`). What this does is get anything between `<table>` and `</table>` tokens. Good [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for regex with python. Take a look at `re.findall()`.
4. Now you are left with table data. You can use regular expressions again to get data for each row, then regex on each row to get columns. `re.findall()` is the key again.

Comment: This has got it, took the time to break it down and find an expression and I've got life back into my console. Haven't quite got the table, but I'll let you know when I do.